# SSO between Experience Cloud and external E-commerce site

Tags: connected-apps, single-sign-on, experience-cloud, saml, identity-provider

The client needs Is the following:
From the e-commerce (external hosted) when they want to register,they are redirected to the salesforce community Page where they can log-in or register. After they register,they Land on the community and a verification email Is sent to their email. Then,when they log in with their credentials they are both logged in the community sfdc and the e-commerce if they come back to it.

Can i achieve this using SSO/SAML,and Salesforce as Identity Provider? Is salesforce the Service Provider too in this case? I'm missing how you can be logged in both system and what/Who Is the IDP.

Thank you all!

Comment: SF is the identity provider in this case, your eCommerce app is the service provider. You can use SAML or OpenID Connect.https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity_basics/identity_basics_protocols

Comment: Ok thank you @identigral! Can i use the community as Identity Provider too?

Comment: Yes. Once you enable the identity provider service at the org level, it auto-enables it for all Digital Exp sites.

Comment: Do you think i Need some special Identity licenses for the users to permit the SSO?

Comment: [Experience Cloud licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.exp_cloud_plan_licenses.htm&type=5) are a typical requirement but you might have other options. Talk to your Salesforce account rep.